# undefined is not an object (evaluting_'this2.pros.navigation')

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

1. App.js

   ```
   import {DrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
   import SettingsScreen from './src/components/SettingsScreen';
   import UploadsScreen from './src/components/UploadsScreen';
   const DrawerExample = DrawerNavigator(
     {
          First:{
           path:'/',
           screen:UploadsScreen,
          },
          Second:{
           path:'/sent',
           screen:SettingsScreen,
          },
     },
       {
         initialRouteName:'First',
         DrawerPosition:'left'
       }

     );
      export default DrawerExample;
   ```

2.SettingScreen.js

```
export default class SettingsScreen extends Component{
static navigationOptions ={
    tabBarLabel: 'Screen1',
    drawerIcons: () =>{
        return (
                <Image style={{width:5, height:5}}
        source={require('../images/notification-icon.png')} />
            );
        }
    }
 render(){
    return <View style={
        {
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
    }
 }>
 <Text style={{fontSize:30, color:'green'}}>
 Screen1
 </Text>
 <Button
    onPress={() => this.pros.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
    title="Open DrawNavigator"
    />
 </View>
 }
}
```

3.Uploadscreen.js

```
export default class UploadsScreen extends Component{
static navigationOptions ={
    tabBarLabel: 'Screen2',
    drawerIcons: () =>{
        return (
            <Image style={{width:5, height:5}}
        source={require('../images/home-icon.png')} />
            );
        }
    }
 render
 (){
    return <View style={
        {
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
    }
 }>
 <Text style={{fontSize:30, color:'blue'}}>
 Screen1
 </Text>
 <Button
    onPress={() => this.pros.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
    title="Open DrawNavigator"
    />
 </View>
 }
}
```

- navigating to any page it shows the same error undefined is not an
  object (evaluting_'this2.pros.navigation')  while trying the other
  method routing flux it show the same and in drawer navigation its
  same i am stuck  Anybody knws the solution please let me knw....

Comment: You need to use `this.props.navigation.navigate`

Comment: i have used it in  screens

Comment: Ands thats a spelling mistake but now nothing happens only yellow error box is pop up

Comment: Use `this.props.navigation.openDrawer();
` if you have latest version of `react-navigation`

Comment: There is a typo, `this.pros.navigation` should be `this.props.navigation`